# How to implement multi-class hinge loss in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I want to implement multi-class hinge loss in tensorflow. The formulation is as follows:

[image: multi-class hinge loss function]

I find it difficult to get the second max prediction probability when the prediction is correct. I tried to use tf.nn.top_k to calculate it, but unfortunately tf.nn.top_k doesn't implement the gradient operation. So how can I implement this?

Comment: which version of TF do you have? In latest version `top_k` has gradients

Comment: @csz-carrot I know it's been a while since you asked this question but if you were able to make it work, it would help lots of people, if you could post the tensorflow implementation of the loss here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`top_k` has gradients, added in version 0.8 [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/dbc57b9068da9b823dbcc3101e599da6f65f658a)

Comment: Thank you. I changed from TF 0.7 to 0.8.

Comment: ps: as another user notes, it would be useful to have a working example of hinge loss in TensorFlow, for future doc purposes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding another implementation with three lines of code
scores: unscaled scores, tensor, shape=(n_classes, batch_size), dtype=float32
classes: tensor, shape=(batch_size, batch_size), dtype=float32

For implementing above loss with choosing the most violated class instead of considering all classes

```
#H - hard negative for each sample
H = tf.reduce_max(scores * (1 - classes), 0)    
L = tf.nn.relu((1 - scores + H) * classes)
final_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_max(L, 0))
```

Another implementation where we sum over all negative classes

```
# implements loss as sum_(j~=y) max(0, 1 - s(x, y) + s(x, j))
def multiclasshingeloss1(scores, classes):
    true_classes = tf.argmax(classes, 0)
    idx_flattened = tf.range(0, scores.get_shape()[1]) * scores.get_shape()[0]+\
    tf.cast(true_classes, dtype=tf.int32)
    true_scores = tf.gather(tf.reshape(tf.transpose(scores), [-1]),
                            idx_flattened)
    L = tf.nn.relu((1 - true_scores + scores) * (1 - classes))
    final_loss = tf.reduce_mean(L)
    return final_loss
```

You can minimize the transposes here based on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation is as follows but I think there must be more efficient implementations.

logits: unscaled scores, tensor, shape=(batch_size, n_classes)

label: tensor, shape=(batch_size, )

batch_size, n_classes: int

```py
def multi_class_hinge_loss(logits, label, batch_size, n_classes):
    # get the correct logit
    flat_logits = tf.reshape(logits, (-1,))
    correct_id = tf.range(0, batch_size) * n_classes + label
    correct_logit = tf.gather(flat_logits, correct_id)

    # get the wrong maximum logit
    max_label = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
    top2, _ = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k=2, sorted=True)
    top2 = tf.split(1, 2, top2)
    for i in xrange(2):
        top2[i] = tf.reshape(top2[i], (batch_size, ))
    wrong_max_logit = tf.select(tf.equal(max_label, label), top2[1], top2[0])

    # calculate multi-class hinge loss
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(0., 1. + wrong_max_logit - correct_logit))
```